# Base64 Multer NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

Utilizei o `multer` na minha API, fiz o upload de imagem, tudo certinho, mas gostaria de usar base64, ai entra a duvida (eu não sei muito sobre `base64`), qual a melhor forma de se fazer? eu fiz uma de uma forma, converti a imagem direto da minha `API`, e armazeno o `base64` no banco, porem, dessa maneira não tenho a imagem no meu servidor.

```
router.post('/profile', multer({dest: "./public/uploads/"}).single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
        let fileInfo = []
        let bitmap = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path), 'base64')
        fileInfo.push({
            "originalName": req.file.originalName,
            "size": req.file.size,
            "base64": new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64")
        })

        fs.unlink(req.file.path)

        let query = "UPDATE ?? SET ?? = ? WHERE ?? = ?"
        let table = ["users_info", "avatar", fileInfo[0].base64, "id_user", req.body.id]
        query = mysql.format(query, table)
        connection.query(query, (err, rows) => {
            if(err){
                res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar query do Mysql"});
            }else{
                res.json({"Error": false, "Message": "Successo", "base64": fileInfo[0].base64});
            }
        })
    })
```

Então, lembrei, que quando eu fazia upload (enviado do app), eu mandava em base64 já, então minha duvida é, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? sendo que quero armazenar as imagens no meu servidor.

Comment: Tu quer armazenar as imagens no servidor como arquivos em vez de armazenar no banco como base64? Nesse caso bastaria substituir o campo onde salva a imagem por um campo onde salvaria o caminho da imagem e passar a salvar a imagem em um diretório de uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um tempo, consegui resolver meu problema, deixo aqui a solução para caso, alguem passe pelo mesmo problema.

```
router.post('/avatar', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
    let base64Data = req.body.base64
    let newName    = req.body.avatar
    fs.writeFile("public/images/" + newName, base64Data, 'base64', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            return res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao fazer upload de imagem"})   
        }else{
            let query = "UPDATE ?? SET ?? = ? WHERE ?? = ?"
            let table = ["users_info", "avatar", newName, "id_user", req.body.id]
            query = mysql.format(query, table)
            pool.query(query, (err, rows) => {
                if(err){
                    return res.json({"Error": true, "Message": "Erro ao executar query do Mysql"})
                }
                return res.json({"Error": false, "Message": "Successo", "avatar": url + 'images/' + newName})
            })
        }
    })
})
```